# Data or Incoming Request Validation Framework or Best Approach

Tags: java, web-services, validation

Hi fellow programmers,

I was wondering what is the best way to perform a validation of the requests received on Web service? I know there might be several ways but what my requirement is that I have around 1100 clients which sends requests on my published web service. Now the real problem here is that every client has its own validation rules for example for one client the company name should not be more than 10 characters and it should be alphanumeric and for other clients there's no requirement of company name being alphanumeric it just needs to be plain string less than 30 characters. So on and so forth. Fields which needs validation are more than 50. I should have a database which will save the validations rules per client and these validation rules will be applied to the upcoming requests by that client. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? What should i use and how should i do it? What is the best way to perform these kind of validations? Any framework available? Thanks is advance.

Comment: Hi, do you use XML or JSON?

Comment: As of now XML but in future JSON also (but its not going to happen in the near future).

Comment: Ok you can provide a different document definition depending which client. For JSON you can take a look to JSON SCHEMA

Comment: Ok but still it doesn't answer my original question and it is close to impossible to provide different document definitions to each client (if i understood you correctly).

Comment: Ok the idea is to provide a definition document depending which client. You can check validate it when the client provide a request

Comment: Thanks for your comment. See in my scenario it is not possible to maintain these many documents for each client. Its just not possible so there has to be an another solution.